Weirdness with URI class in .NET
I found a weirdness with URI class in my .net framework 4.8 project.
The strange thing is that the same code works differently in my simple console application and in the local copy of the production application. Both are running on the same computer, and on the same framework version.
Here is the code:
var test = new Uri("https://myhost.net/Publications/te%21st%C3%87.pdf");
Console.WriteLine(test.AbsolutePath);

So the filename is te!stÇ.pdf. And Ç is Turkish letter.
Everything works great in my local app.
But in my local copy of production app (which is running in IIS) it  returns a different output:



Application
Output




Local app
/Publications/te%21st%C3%87.pdf


Local copy of prod
/Publications/te!st%C3%87.pdf



So it decodes %21 to ! for some reason. But if i replace Turkish Ç with English C then %21 is not decoded. Any ideas what is going on?

Some context is definitely missing from the question. The file path should either url encoded (te%21st%C3%87.pdf) or decoded (te!stÇ.pdf). I can not think of any scenario when the decode is only partially applied.

Could you please check the LocalPath for both application instances?

@PeterCsala LocalPath is /Publications/te!stÇ.pdf in both local console app and prod app. There is no difference. But AbsolutePath is different

@PeterCsala also i only noticed that for !. I tried to change it to other symbols like $, %, ~ and others and there is no issue with them, they are not decoded when calling AbsolutePath. Looks like it only happens for "!+Unicode letter" combination.

I can not think of any scenario when the decode is only partially applied. - this is exactly what happens. And I don't have a single idea why and how. It is probably somehow related to culture or other globalization stuff.

Even if I set all culture to Turkish I still could not reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sTbavn (I could not set the culture with .NET 4.7.2 runtime because it throws SecurityException)

@PeterCsala looks like i found a way to reproduce it. See UPDATED section

I think instead of updating the original question you should post an answer since it solves your problem as far as I can tell.

It looks like I found the cause of the problem and found a way to reproduce/solve it.
This seems to only happen in the WEB apps (API in my case) and not console apps. And targetFramework in httpRuntime should be less than 4.7.2.
Here is my original web.config:
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>

So targetFramework="4.5.2" in httpRuntime was causing this weird behavior.
After i changed 4.5.2 to 4.8, the code new Uri("https://myhost.net/Publications/te%21st%C3%87.pdf").AbsolutePath returns /Publications/te%21st%C3%87.pdf instead of /Publications/te!st%C3%87.pdf
The issue is not reproducible when version is 4.7.2 or higher. Looks like they fixed that in 4.7.2 despite the fact that they did not explicitly say this in the release notes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.7.x#net-framework-472
